# Playing a video on Raspberry Pi OS startup

Tags: linux, shell, cron, raspberry-pi4, raspberry-pi-os

I need to run a script to play a video when I turn on my Raspberry Pi 4. I'm using crontab to run my script which opens a video with [mpv](https://mpv.io/).
When I run the script normally, it works fine and the video is being played.
The problem is, when i boot the raspberry, the script automatically runs but mpv doesn't .

here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
VIDEOPATH="/home/pi/Desktop/my-movie.mkv"
SERVICE="mpv"


while true; do 
  echo "playing "+$VIDEOPATH
  $SERVICE --fs --start=00:00:00 $VIDEOPATH
done
```

I added this line to crontab:

```
@reboot /home/pi/Desktop/my-script.sh
```

I'm totally stuck in this. Any help saves my life!

Comment: `When I turn on my Raspberry Pi 4` When exactly? After your desktop environment has loaded? If so, my guess is that a better approach would be making a simple `systemd` service instead with appropriate `After`/`Requires` dependencies on whatever service launches your desktop environment.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what i meant. Thanks for the suggestion, I tried systemd but when i start the service manually, I expect the video to play, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most practical solution I found to run GUI programs on startup is using Autostart.
I created a .desktop file at /etc/xdg/autostart directory:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/display.desktop
```

when `display` would be a custom name for my script.
I added following lines the display.desktop :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Play a video
Exec=mpv --fs --start=00:00:00 path-to-my-video
```

Saved the file and reboot the Pi.

```
sudo reboot
```

As soon as my Pi boots up, my GUI program automatically start as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_profile
VIDEOPATH="/home/pi/Desktop/my-movie.mkv"
SERVICE="mpv"


while true; do 
  echo "playing "+$VIDEOPATH
  $SERVICE --fs --start=00:00:00 $VIDEOPATH
done
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. I tried this approach but nothing changed :(